# Xcode - bundle too large

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, visual-studio-2012

I have one C++ project, it's a dynamic lib. When I compile it on Windows (Visual Studio 2012) its `300 kB` large. But when I compile it on Mac with XCode, it has `3.9 MB` binary inside the bundle.

I have the optimization level `Fastest, Smallest [-Os]` option selected.

`Debug symbols` are also turned off.

The project are the same, the only extra framework is `Cocoa.framework`, which I need to sucessfuly compile the project. Could Cocoa.framework link so much?

Is this some bad linker's work?

I can compile this with LLVM GCC 4.2 or Apple LLVM Compiler 4.2, the size is the same.

Any ideas how to reduce the .bundle size?

Comment: Why is it a `.bundle` and not a `.dylib` or `.framework`?

Comment: Why Cocoa.framework is a problem?

Comment: On Windows its .dll, the same philosophy should be on mac, but the output at template project is set to .bundle and all is working smoothly, so I guess the .bundle format should persist.

Comment: @dbasic who said its a problem?

Comment: @bartimar: I mean is it due to Cocoa.framework?

Comment: @dbasic: that is what I am asking here :D

Comment: Check if Cocoa.framework is linked dynamically or statically.

Comment: I dont see this option in XCode, Visual Studio is much better in this...

Comment: Wow! Visual Studio can build code to run on a Mac or iOS?  I had no idea.  Snark aside, perhaps you should check to see if you have symbols turned on or stripped.

Comment: Haha :) There are so many combinations setting the xcode project... i tried to turn on and off the striping and so on. What can be turned off to make the smallest binary?

Comment: We need more information! Does your code actually contain any class concerning Cocoa.framework? If it doesn't, just don't link with it!

Comment: No, my part of code doesnt contain any Cocoa.framework calls. But when i didnt link Cocoa, I have got some errors, so I need it (actually one of my working frameworks need it). But Linker should optimize it and use only the necessary part, right?

Comment: Do you generate a bundle with universal binary settings ?

Comment: What do you mean by "universal binary settings"?

Answer (score 1):

I'd hazard a guess this is occurring due to exported symbols from your project. We're not talking about debug symbols here, but symbol table entries for every class, method, constructor, exception-handler unwind segments and so on.  The latter category accounts for a lot of them in a project using exceptions and the standard library.

If you're using STL, boost or anything else with a lot of templates, you'll also have the specialisations for every type you used them with (often the entire class - not just methods), with weak linkage.   The length of symbols-names gets huge with template expansion and C++ name mangling of parameter types.

When compiling windows DLLs,  symbols must be explicitly *exported* - either using compiler directive (often using the `DLLExport` macro) or a linker symbol export list.

On MacOSX and ELF-based *NIX systems it's the other way around: they're all exported by default.  The linker has no way of knowing what the module might be linked to, and therefore which ones are useful or not.    In reality, an application usually only really need to export `main` and any unresolved symbols.

There is also no distinction for C++ class members marked as `private`.  You get the symbols for these too.

This [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/dynamiclibraries/100-Articles/DynamicLibraryDesignGuidelines.html) from Apple describes how to limit visibility of symbols.  You certainly used to be able to do this with `gcc` - but a quick look at the equivalent for `clang` suggests it's not as well supported there.

Comment: This looks interesting, but im kinda programmer newbie, could you suggest some xcode settings to try? Or what should I do to reduce the size. I'm sure the 3 MB binary must have very much redundant data.

Comment: Sure it does.   Does size really worry you here?  Since most of the symbol names are ASCII text, it ought to be fairly compressible.

Comment: Try doing `nm -a <objectfilename>` and see what you get.  Those marked  `T` are exported from your code.  Those marked `t` are local, but are still in the symbol table.   I've just found a symbol that's 100 characters long in one of my modules, and there were plenty more like that.

Comment: BTW: There is no distinction in ELF or Mach-O between libraries and application relocatable object files.   The difference is simply convention about what's inside them.

Comment: The size really worries me, I need to sell non compressed file, and when customer gets one for Windows 300 kB big and the same for Mac 3 MB big, its so weird :)

Comment: I have to say, this wouldn't bother me.  I well remember using Qt3, and debug build of the library was >100Mb - which was linked against every time on build.  No a problem really.

Answer (score -1):

The inflated binary size is the result of compiled binary having debugging symbols.

Go to "Project"/"Edit Project Settings" menu item, click on build tab, under "Code Generation" section, uncheck Generate Debug Symbols. You can type in "sym" in search field to help find it.